# googleapi: Error 403: 567x@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I stay trying my project based on this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-smart-home-cloud

**My issue is:**

cloudfunctions.googleapis.com
google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction
projects/casaminha-2e0ca/locations/us-central1/functions/syncOnRemove
neuberfran@gmail.com
Build failed: could not resolve source: googleapi: Error 403: 567xxxx1772xxxxxxxxxxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., forbidden
com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcClientException:  APPLICATION_ERROR;google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1/ArgoAdminV1.CreateBuild;could not resolve source: googleapi: Error 403: 5676xxxxxx062@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., forbidden;AppErrorCode=3;StartTimeMs=999999999999540;unknown;ResFormat=AUTOMATIC;ServerTimeSec=0.999999999999999;LogBytes=256;Non-

I deleted in 27/jul/2021 cloud build or  cloud run (I don't use cloud run in my project) I deleted in GCP console. I thought that was what was giving credential error in my action project on google. **Then I started to receive the current error**.

I remember that the service account I deleted was associated with google controller only (**there was a question mark there**)

I think the gcf command will rebuild this. But not sure if this is correct. And I also don't know how to use **gcf-sources-<PROJECT_NUMBER>-**

I stay trying actions on google, using firestore and GCP.

**commands:**

firebase --project casaminha-2e0ca functions:config:set cloudiot.region=us-central1

firebase --project casaminha-2e0ca functions:config:set smarthome.id=567617xxxxxxxxxxxxxx9r9upjxxxxxxx0t.apps.googleusercontent.com smarthome.secret=D99999999999

firebase --project casaminha-2e0ca functions:config:set smarthome.key="99999999"

firebase deploy --project casaminha-2e0ca

**THis is my project in github**:https://github.com/neuberfran/firebasefunction

**This is my issueTracker**: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194942955?pli=1

Can you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the Cloud Function the Cloud Build API must be enabled in order to deploy your Cloud Function, it's well documented in the tutorial([Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-nodejs#before-you-begin)). The Cloud Build Service Account will automatically generate when you enable the Cloud Build service in your Google Cloud project and it looks like:

```
[PROJECT-ID]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
```

Regarding this:

> I deleted in 27/jul/2021 cloud build or cloud run (I don't use cloud run in my project) I deleted in GCP console

Please note, [deleting Service Account:](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#deleting)

> When you delete a service account, applications will no longer have access to Google Cloud resources through that service account.

And based on your [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194942955#comment7), it seems the solution is to recover your deleted Service Account. The deleted Service account can recover within 30 days. To undelete or recover, you must find the the numeric ID or ACCOUNT_ID for the deleted service account that you can get in Cloud Logging/Log Explorer, [here is the tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#finding-numeric-id).

Once you have obtained the numeric ID or the ACCOUNT_ID, run the following in your CLI or Cloud Shell or Cloud SDK:

```
gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete ACCOUNT_ID
```

output:

```
restoredAccount:
  email: SA_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  etag: BwWWE7zpApg=
  name: projects/PROJECT_ID/serviceAccounts/SA_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  oauth2ClientId: '123456789012345678901'
  projectId: PROJECT_ID
  uniqueId: 'ACCOUNT_ID'
```

## UPDATE:

The root cause of the error was missing the `Cloud Build Service Account` permission and it was solved by adding this permission.

Comment: tks. But not solved yet. I put this: 
resource.type="service_account"
resource.labels.email_id="neuberfran@gmail.com"
"DeleteServiceAccount"

and this:
gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete 2716495694158255

and the result was not satisfactory. How to solve?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fqX5r9GY09a2zZbsoGbxQZ_6eY9JTSTw?usp=sharing

Comment: About this part.: [PROJECT-ID]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com (according to the pictures on google drive) I see important differences between the project that is the reason for this thread and another project (which has another type of error). Differences that point to the solution of my issue https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oLIU1tDprVIw3rzM8OBpsRwx7ChVdLWp

Comment: Don't use a new project, use the project where you deleted your service account. Before running the undelete command, make sure that you set a Google Cloud project on your CLI using `gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]`.

Comment: Solved. But I didn't have to undelete in service (or anything else from the GCP) that I might have deleted. The google drive images were critical for me to see the difference between 1 new and what was missing in my GCP/AOG service in the GCP console. My casaminha-2e0ca@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com was missing:Cloud Build Service Account.  If you want, please edit something in your answer for me to consider it correct, otherwise I will answer. Thank's

Comment: Glad to know @neuberfran! Upvote on my answer is enough when you feel that it helps you, it still better if you provide your own answer with full details to help others.

Comment: @neuberfran, please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I hadn't delete the service account, just the IAM roles for the service account.

The solution is to go to the IAM page, and add the principal:
`[PROJECT-ID]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`
with role: `Cloud Build Service Account`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had just recently enabled the Cloud Build API on my project and I merely had to wait an extra 2 minutes and it worked. I'm glad I didn't go messing with the IAM roles in vain while I waited!